# I can't use my git alias

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu

How to use the git alias?

I have configured them in `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
    g = "git"
    go = "git checkout"
```

And I can see them with `git config --get-regexp alias`:

```
alias.g git
alias.go git checkout
```

But when I try to use them, it displays the following:

```
$ g
g: command not found

$ go
The program 'go' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install golang-go
```

How cai I make them to work?

Comment: Do you have an alias in your local repo `config` file?

Comment: @JakeHenningsgaard, I don't. If I do that can I call the alias without calling `git` before?

Comment: I set the alias (`g = "git"`) in my global `.gitconfig` file and it worked.  I then created an alias in the local git repo `config` file (`g = "ls"`).  This local one overwrite the global.  This doesn't fix your problem but it might be a start.

Comment: @JakeHenningsgaard, If I use it on local git repo, I still need to type `git` before the alias. @pedrorijo91 pointed a neat solution. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

git alias are not used like that. git aliases are used for git, meaning:

your alias file should be something like:

```
    [alias]

        co = checkout
```

and be used like `git co <args>`

the alias is used only for the after 'git' command.

Comment: I see, it works. Thanks! How would I replace `git checkout` for `go`? Is it possible?

Comment: that would need a bash/shell alias (depending on what yo are using), not a git alias. for instance, I have on my `.bash_profile`: alias lsa='ls -a'

Comment: there are many resources with better info that the one I could provide. just as an example: http://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-bash-alias

Comment: Sweet! By editing the `~/.bashrc`, I was able to make the alias `g` working: `alias g='git'`. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

You have to type

```
git g
```

or

```
git go
```

Comment: I was able to get it to work just running the alias: `g branch -a`

Answer (score 0):

First, as another user pointed out, you have to use git aliases only inside git. What it means is that your aliases **must** be used like this :

```
git ALIAS ...
```

Then, don't put any " " around your aliases (but you could, there's nothing wrong with it). Just write them like this :

```
[alias]
    co = checkout
    ci = commit
    st = status
```

If you want to setup aliases to call git with, you have to add them to your ~/.bashrc file.

```
alias gs='git status'
alias go='git checkout'
```

Hope it helps

Comment: You don't have to omit the quotations.  Mine works with or without them.

Comment: You are right. I just don't use them but you easily could. I'll edit.